# Sorting a list of pojos in Java

Tags: java-8

I would like to sort a list of Pojos based on the field (sortField) and order (sortOrder) parameters passed in.  I have this working (for 6 fields) -

```
switch (sortField) {
  case "field1" :
    if (sortOrder == "asc") {
      list.sort((lItem1, lItem2) -> lItem1.getField1().compareTo(lItem2.getField1()));
    } else {
      list.sort((lItem1, lItem2) -> lItem2.getField1().compareTo(lItem1.getField1()));
    }
  break; 
  case "field2" :
    if (sortOrder == "asc") {
      list.sort((lItem1, lItem2) -> lItem1.getField2().compareTo(lItem2.getField2()));
    } else {
      list.sort((lItem1, lItem2) -> lItem2.getField2().compareTo(lItem1.getField2()));
    }
  break;
  //...
}
```

This works perfectly but feels a little bit clunky and I just wondered if anyone could point me to a (relatively simple!) tidier & more graceful way to do it ?

Comment: use different Comperators

Comment: Comparators and [thenComparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: do you really need to name your sortfield and/or the sort order as `String`? If not, then you could just use `Comparator.comparing` directly, specify the function to apply and apply `reversed` on the resulting comparator depending on your preferred sort order. @Flown's answer is a good example for that.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I like a combination of the 2 answers (Map of comparators but turning order into a function (need to look up reversed).  Apologies, I hadn't realised there was a different site  codereview.stackexchange.com so unless anyone tells me differently I'll close this tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `Map<String, Comparator<MyPojo>>` and use it like:

```
Map<String, Comparator<MyPojo>> comparators = new HashMap<>();
comparators.put("field1", Comparator.comparing(MyPojo::getField1));
comparators.put("field2", Comparator.comparing(MyPojo::getField2));
//...

Comparator<MyPojo> comp = comparators.get(sortField);

list.sort("asc".equals(sortOrder) ? comp : comp.reversed());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, there are few things you can consider like reusability and duplicate codes.

**Duplicate codes:**

```
if (sortOrder == "asc") 
        {
            list.sort((lItem1, lItem2) -> lItem1.getField2().compareTo(lItem2.getField2()));
        }
        else
        {
            list.sort((lItem1, lItem2) -> lItem2.getField2().compareTo(lItem1.getField2()));
        }
```

To solve this, I would write either two separate methods to do sorting in asc or desc separately or write a single method to do both with parameter to define sorting order.

**Solutions**

**Example1:**

```
public List sortedList(List items, boolean isOrderAscending) { //do stuffs with items based on isOrderAscending and return sorted items}
```

**Example2:**

```
public List sortedListInAscendingOrder(List items) { //return ascending ordered list}
public List sortedListInDescendingOrder(List items) { //return descending ordered list}
```

I would even write a method to get sorting order from sortOrder.

```
public boolean isInAscending(String sortOrder) { //return true or false based on sortOrder}
```

**Compiling whole:**

```
List sortedItems = sortedList(items, isOrderAscending(sortedOrder));
```

Maybe after giving enough thoughts, whole field part can be altered in a more elegant way.